# What if i can't have an oscilloscope?

Tags: modeling

I need to recognise some good computer softwares that i can use to model, simulate and measure my DIY electronic circuits if i can't have(afford) an oscilloscope to do so. Would you please name for me a few?

Comment: Ltspice is a good start

Comment: There are a few cheap USB ones available on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/usb-oscilloscope). You can use softwares like LTspice if you don't want to buy anything at all. There are always pros and cons depending on your exact purpose.

Comment: Models and simulations are a good start anyway, but what you really need a 'scope for is figuring out why your real circuit doesn't behave like the simulation. If you are a student, [Analog Discovery 2](http://store.digilentinc.com/analog-discovery-2-100msps-usb-oscilloscope-logic-analyzer-and-variable-power-supply/) has discounts, which may be worth investigating.

Comment: If you have a PC that is available for your own use you can use the sound card as a low frequency oscilloscope. | You can get very low cost basic oscilloscopes from China. How much can you afford to spend on an oscilloscope? ($ 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 ?) | What country are you in ?- may affect advice greatly. | Do you have a laptop or desktop PC of your own? If so what brand and model?

Comment: As mentioned above LTSpice is a good one, although it all depends on how complicated the circuit is. If I'm just building a small circuit with a couple of transistors I usually just use [Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html)

Comment: An oscilloscope is worth having, there will be many times you will use it. Could you not find a second hand one. Older CRT type scopes are not much money.

Comment: thanks Roger Rowland, and everybody else in here for your helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Proteus software which good one

Comment: While this certainly is more than 15 characters on Stack Exchange we generally prefer people to explain their answer in at least a few lines. Why try that? What does it do? Maybe add a link.

Comment: I'm not sure if Proteus can really do any kind of analysis, and I guess it's often used for Modeling and Prototyping, are you sure about what you suggested??

Comment: @M-J Yes Proteus can be used for simulation and modelling.Cant use for measuring .   A computer based  (low cost) oscilloscope cant support high bandwidth . http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/experiments/chpt-4/pc-oscilloscope/    Use USB based Oscilloscope ..